# C# Hooking a Console Application to Notepad

Tags: c#, process, hook

What i want to do is create a simple windows application that will hook itself onto NotePad and then simulate a keystroke.  I have the process of opening up NotePad, bringing it to the foreground and then simulate the number 1 being pressed.  However, if I click off of notepad, whatever is active becomes what is being typed in.

How do I bind this application to notepad, so that I can click and type in whatever, and this application will still push commands into notepad?

[This is the DLL i'm using to simulate keypressing](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WindowsInput;

namespace NotePadTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
        string lpWindowName);
        // Activate an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

            if (processes.Length == 0)
            {

                Process.Start("notepad.exe");
                processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

            }
            if (processes.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not find notepad huh....");
            }

            IntPtr WindowHandle = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(WindowHandle);

            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_1);

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the first post that has had 25+ views and not one comment :(

Comment: I'm looking into things if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Internally, the `WindowsInput` project uses the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) native windows call, which looks like it just simulates a hardware message for the key-press which is then processed by Windows which will route it to the active application. You probably need to work with the native method calls yourself and use the `SendMessage` winapi function to send a key press to the `Process`'s `MainWindowHandle`.

Comment: @Anthony - thanks for the comment, but i'm not sure how even that would hook into notepad...

Comment: Why not check for notepad in the foreground on keypress?

Comment: @Mike what is it you are actually trying to do (meaning learn something, build something bigger than this test, etc)?

Comment: @Sarah because then the user would be constantly fighting between the two screen (notepad and whatevr)

Comment: @MikeCheel A little of both, basically how to hook keyboard events into another application

Comment: What you are trying to do does not require hooks. Are you really trying to learn about hooks or how to manipulate windows that don't belong to your application?

Comment: @MikeCheel Hmm, I would have assumed it required hooks.  Trying to manipulate other applications I guess is the best term, even though the other applications are mine...

Comment: I *believe* what you need to understand then is how to use the winapi properly. The key functions to look at will be located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919(v=vs.85).aspx and you can get their .Net equivalents here: http://www.pinvoke.net/ Specifically look at SendMessage, GetWindow, and related. Those functions will allow you to reference windows by handle and then manipulate them.

Comment: If you want to automate, use automation

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the handle of the window you want to type in you can use the [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. You just have to google the virtual keycodes.

Comment: I think my only problem with PostMessage/SendMessage is it requires wpf

Comment: I dont think so since its a native windows api function in the User32.dll library just like the FindWindow function in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to interface with `Notepad.exe` via [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You will need to use `P/Invoke` techniques to call this from `User32.dll`:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal static class NativeMethods
{
  // This method signature is derived from MSDN's PostMessage declaration.
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);

  // Other p/invoke methods go here, such as FindWindow...
}
```

You can locate `Notepad` with [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), allowing you to get the window's handle (`HWND`).

Once you do so, you can post [Keyboard Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to that window. Those notifications simulate keyboard input and are only for that window, even if the window is minimized or otherwise not the foreground window.

The messages of importance will be [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Many of these take in **scan codes** instead of **virtual key codes**, meaning you will need to translate back and forth. This is done with [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). All of the WM commands take specific forms of their `LPARAM` and `WPARAM` values, so check the MSDN documentation of what it expects.

There's a tool called `Spy++` that (used to?) comes with Visual Studio that lets you peek at these messages. It's a great debugging/reverse engineering tool for this type of stuff.

Using all of the above Win32 API, you should be able to send keystrokes to an external window.